# Labelling every nth tick mark

Tags: r, axis-labels

I am plotting an axis with

```
a <- factor(letters[seq( from = 1, to = 26 )])
b <- 1:26
plot(a, b, axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = a, labels = a, las = 2)
```

How can I get **all the tick marks** but only **every nth label**, e.g. (every 7th):

[image]

Comment: `a[seq(1, 100, by = 10)]` ?

Comment: @Pascal `Error in axis(1, at = a, labels = a[seq(1, length(datum),  :  'at' and 'labels' lengths differ, 86 != 13` The problem is that I want all the tick marks but not all the labels.

Comment: Of course they are different lengths. You made a subset of the `labels` without making the same for `at`.

Comment: If your x axis is a "series of dates", I think you should treat them as `Date`s and not `character`. Then you can use `axis.Date` instead. Several nice examples in the help text on how to create a relevant `seq`uence and how to `format` labels. (ok, dates disappeared in OP's last edit...)

Comment: you can create label for each =="" and than add needed label `dt=data.frame(x=1:20,y=1:20,a=letters[1:20],stringsAsFactors = F)
plot(dt$y~dt$x,xaxt = 'n')
aa=rep("",20)
aa[seq(1, 20, by = 5)] =dt$a[seq(1, 20, by = 5)] 
axis(1, at = dt$x, labels = aa, las = 2)`

Comment: @Henrik Actually the x-axis is `as.POSIXct(substring(logs$request.time, 2, 27), format = "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z")` and the labels ("a") are `unique(strftime(logs$request.time, "%a %d.%m."))`. But look at my symplified question.

Comment: @Batanichek Thanks, that's a good idea. I guess I'll just have to use empty labels where I want none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `axis` twice, first to draw all tick marks and then again to put the labels:

```
c = a[seq(1, length(a),7)]
axis(1, at=a, labels = FALSE)
axis(1, at=c, labels = c, las = 2)
```